# нужна помощ с представлениями Django

Tags: django, python-3.6

вопрос следующий: как я могу представить эту функцию в виде CBV? 
если не трудно, то хотелось бы понять а не просто увидеть готовый вариант.

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products_list = products.filter(category=category)
        paginator = Paginator(products_list, 3)

        try:
            page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
        except:
            page = 1

        try:
            products = paginator.page(page)
        except():
            products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/list.html',
                  {'category': category,
                   'categories': categories,
                   'products': products,
                   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CategoryListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Product # Указывает для какой модели ищем

    paginate_by = 20 # Кол-во элементов на странице

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.model.objects.filter(category__slug=<slug>) # как получить slug не помню, но точно там надо полазить в настройках
```

Вам останется добавить файл шаблона, что то вроде /_list.html (для detail view)